# Cross product for vectors with more than 10 dimensions in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I currently have two vectors of shape (300L,) each. However, when I am trying to compute cross product between them through numpy cross function, it's throwing up the following error:
`z = np.cross(x,y)`

> C:\Users\SMG059\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.pyc in cross(a, b, axisa, axisb, axisc, axis)
>      1525            "(dimension must be 2 or 3)")
>      1526     if a.shape[-1] not in (2, 3) or b.shape[-1] not in (2, 3):
>   -> 1527         raise ValueError(msg)
>      1528 
>      1529         # Create the output array
>
> ValueError: incompatible dimensions for cross product
>   (dimension must be 2 or 3)

Can someone please tell me how to compute cross product for large vectors?

Comment: The vector cross product is only defined in three dimensions. Do you mean you have two arrays, each of 300, 3-dimensional vectors?

Comment: I think what you're looking for is the determinant of a matrix.  The cross product of two 3-length vectors is calculated using a determinant.  Is that correct? http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.det.html

Comment: Also worth noting: Cross product only exists for vectors of 3 and 7 dimensions.  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/424482/cross-product-in-mathbb-rn  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/720813/do-four-dimensional-vectors-have-a-cross-product-property

Comment: I actually want to determine the angle between the arrays. Is there a way to do that? That's why I needed cross product.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't the [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) that you're after, then? `np.dot` will work with an arbitrary number of dimensions.

Comment: @xnx Yes, I am sure about that. Dot product only gives the absolute distance, not information about the positioning as such relative to the axes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment about wanting to know the angle between the arrays, I think you do in fact want the dot product.  For example, here is a function that will give you the angle between two vectors.

```
def angle(vector1, vector2):
    # cos(theta) = v1 dot v2 / ||v1|| * ||v2||
    import numpy
    numerator = numpy.dot(vector1, vector2)
    denominator = numpy.linalg.norm(vector1) * numpy.linalg.norm(vector2)
    x = numerator / denominator if denominator else 0
    return numpy.arccos(x)
```